# Custom divider color for recyclerview in Android not working

Tags: android, kotlin

The following code creates no divider at all:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notifications)

        val titleList = mutableListOf<NotificationsItem>()
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 1", "Description is good!", true))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 2", "Description is good!", true))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 3", "Description is good!", false))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 4", "Description is good!", false))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 5", "Description is good!", true))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 6", "Description is good!", true))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 7", "Description is good!", false))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 8", "Description is good!", true))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 9", "Description is good!", false))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 10", "Description is good!", true))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 11", "Description is good!", false))
        titleList.add(NotificationsItem("Title 12", "Description is good!", false))


        val recycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerNotifications)
        recycler.adapter = NotificationsAdapter(titleList)
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(recycler.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager(this).orientation)
        dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(ColorDrawable(recycler.getContext().resources.getColor(R.color.orange)))
        recycler.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
    }
```

This results in following output:

[image]

If I remove the color change then it works with the default color:

```
val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(recycler.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager(this).orientation)
recycler.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
```

[image]

Why it wont work with the color change?

Comment: Try calling setBounds on the color drawable.  It may think its a 0 size drawable without that.  Or replacing with an xml drawable that specifies the height of the drawable rather than a programatically created color drawable.

Comment: Why is it so hard in Android to do UI customisations? I am from Qt world where you just dont use resource files to build UI widgets. In my project I have got 100 resource files for these customisations thats why I want to avoid creating a new file to change color of a line everytime. Seems like this is normal in Android world. What a waste of time and resources...

Comment: SetBounds does not work either, at least this code doesnt:

val draw = ColorDrawable(recycler.getContext().resources.getColor(R.color.orange))
        draw.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10)
        dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(draw)

Comment: The reason xml is preferred over code is because its easier to read and generally considered a best practice to not mix code and UI.  If you prefer a code creating the UI methodology, you may want to use Compose instead of Views.

Comment: ALso, 10,10,10,10. is not correct.  Those are left, top, right, bottom.  So you explicitly set it to 0 size there.  Try 0, 0, 1000, 10 just for testing purposes

Comment: 0,0,1000,10 doesnt work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a custom color in a `DividerItemDecoration` you need to create a new `ColorDrawable` and override the two public methods `getIntrinsicWidth()` and `getIntrinsicHeight()` and return the drawable's intrinsic width and height respectively.

**Java Example:**

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(recyclerView.getContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_light)){
    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth(){
        return getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight(){
        return (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1f, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
});
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

**Kotlin Example:**

```
val dividerItemDecoration = DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable(object : ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(recyclerView.getContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_light)) {
    override fun getIntrinsicWidth(): Int {
        return resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels / resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi
    }
    
    override fun getIntrinsicHeight(): Int {
        return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1f, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
    }
})
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
```

**Another way with `MaterialDividerItemDecoration`:**

Using the `MaterialDividerItemDecoration` you can simply use the `setDividerColorResource` to change the divider color like the below Kotlin example:

```
val dividerItemDecoration = MaterialDividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.context, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
dividerItemDecoration.setDividerColorResource(recyclerView.context, android.R.color.holo_red_light)
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration)
```

**Result:**

[image: divider]

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!